# Xorg turns laptop screen off on startup on Gentoo

Tags: linux, laptop, nvidia-graphics-card, xorg, gentoo

I am having a problem with my Gentoo installation (binary kernel) where Xorg only turns off my laptop's screen when using Startx, and I can only change TTY to use Gentoo but only on CLI.

This happened after following steps shown on Nvidia Optimus wiki page and rebooting.
Thankfully I have a Windows partition (From where I am asking for help)

- I have tried many solutions including:
- Forcing drivers to load Intel first.
- Loading Nvidia Module with DRM and Modeset.
- Using
  Xrandr but it didn't wanna work even with `export DISPLAY=:0` because
  of Authentication stuff.
- Adding the Xrandr commands to SDDM script at boot
- Changing from SDDM to LightDM

I am really desperate for a solution so if anyone can give me advice or guidance it would be appreciated.

My hardware is as follows:

- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10300H CPU
- Nvidia GeForce GTX 1650 GPU
- 8 GB of RAM
- Binary Kernel